# Swing not displaying unicode characters

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I've got some non-ascii characters I'm trying to display in a Swing JComboBox.  The characters aren't displaying correctly, I get lots of weird characters where the non-ascii characters should be:
[image: Garbled ComboBox]

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] choices = new String[]{"Good's","Bad’s","தமிழ்"};
    for (String s : choices) System.out.println(s);
    JComboBox choiceBox = new JComboBox(choices);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.add(choiceBox);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

(Note the slightly different apostrophe in Bad’s, which is what started this whole thing.)

The `System.out.println` call displays the characters just fine in my terminal.

There are a bunch of questions on SO about this, and they suggest listing fonts from the GraphicsEnvironment and picking only ones that claim to display my characters.  Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work for me.

```
Font font = new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 12);
for (String s : choices) assert font.canDisplayUpTo(s) < 0;
choiceBox.setFont(font);
```

The assert doesn't fail, but still displays garbled characters.

I'm on OSX 10.6.5, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261)

Comment: If you see the characters correct on your terminal, find the font of your terminal and use the same in Swing. Swing does display unicode characters.

Comment: No luck with that.  (My terminal is Menlo Regular 11pt.)

Comment: I arrived here because I am/was more or less doing all these things and my up-tick (`"\u2714"`) still wasn't showing.  The answer was in [Icon in titledBorder title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2519443/108350) -- I was using `Tahoma`, when I changed to `Dialog` as per the sample answer -- I worked.  Encoding alone isn't enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your compiler uses the same encoding as your editor (your editor already uses the same as the console, it seems, and the compiler normally uses the default encoding of the VM, given by the `file.encoding` property).

You can do this by giving the `-encoding` option to the compiler, or the `encoding=` attribute in ant.

Comment: Good advice, but probably not the cause.  The characters are displaying correctly when printed on the console.

Comment: An alternative to specifically setting the source code encoding is to use Unicode literals in the source code.

Comment: @Stephen: This could simply mean that console and editor use something like UTF-8, while compiler and VM use something like Latin-1. This way you have incorrect strings in your classes, but they look right on the console. (It would help if we could see some screenshot of the "garbled characters", certainly.)

Comment: That was totally it!  "javac -encoding utf8 Test.java" did the trick.

Comment: @Keith: Could you make a screenshot of your garbled characters, and put it into the question, too? This could help later people with similar problems to recognize if it is theirs, too.

Answer (score 2):

The font you are trying to use doesn't have the required glyphs. `canDisplay` methods fail for some reason on Mac. On linux and windows your code behaves as expected and assertion fails, but on Mac it doesn't fail. I had a similar problem with using some characters on Mac, I just went with Sans font cause it seemed like the most Unicode complete font. If you check out [this thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2011/Jan/msg00074.html) you will find out its quite common problem. So maybe you want to go with what Costis suggested in comment and also checking out [this](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/reference/faqs/index.html#Q_How_can_I_make_my_custom_font).

Answer (score 2):

Changes the font of JCombobox to Unicode supported font of Tamil.
Download font from 
http://www.ildc.in/Tamil/GIST/htm/otfonts.htm

```
Font font = new Font("TamilFont", Font.PLAIN, 12);
for (String s : choices) assert font.canDisplayUpTo(s) < 0;
choiceBox.setFont(font);
```

Comment: Font font = new Font("TamilFont", Font.PLAIN, 12);
for (String s : choices) assert font.canDisplayUpTo(s) < 0;
choiceBox.setFont(font);

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much.