# Problems displaying french accented characters in .jar file, despite it working perfectly in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar, french

My program displays french accented characters such as `î` and `é`,

[image: perfectly in netbeans.]

But when I built it into a jar file,

[image: it displays accents like this.]

I am using the same .txt file which the file.io/ file handler is reading the data from. Any ideas on how to fix it so the characters display normally? Thanks a bunch.

**EDIT** Just tried my program out my mac... The accents showed up like normal, so possibly it's a fujitsu problem?

Comment: Maybe Netbeans is forcing local to utf-8 when it runs your program. And when your run your program outside of the IDE, you local is set to the operating system one. Thats why I always append "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to my program command line

Comment: learn about UTF-8 here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366048/swing-not-displaying-unicode-characters

Comment: your application is desktop application or web application ?

Comment: @YCF_L My application is a java desktop application, created in netbeans.

Comment: ok did you find any information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366048/swing-not-displaying-unicode-characters

Comment: @YCF_L I sort of get the gist of it, which is that it's an encoding error which occurs during the compiling stage... But I'm a beginner noob so I'm finding it hard to understand how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the charset in your html.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

More information about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518572/utf-8-html-without-bom-displays-strange-characters).